# Angular 10 - Enable ViewChild to get instance regardless of static property

Tags: angular, viewchild

Are there some ways for `@ViewChild` decorator to get the child component's instance in `ngOnInit` as the same from the old `@ViewChild` of angular 6?

I tried something like:

```js
@Component({
  ....
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
  @ViewChild(HelloComponent, {static: true})
  @ViewChild(HelloComponent, {static: false})
  hello: HelloComponent;

  ngOnInit() {
      console.log('Hello Instance',this.hello);
  }
}
```

but it causes me error saying Multiple decorators are not allowed for the same member

Comment: Try using only `static: false`

Answer (score 0):

I'd like to share what I just discovered for @ViewChild for other readers knowledge

to let @ViewChild with `static` property set to false in `ngOnInit`

I have to put it inside setTimeout() like so:

```
@ViewChild(HelloComponent, {static:false}) hello: HelloComponent;

ngOnInit() {
    setTimeout(() => {
        console.log('Hello Instance',this.hello);
    }, 100);
}
```

this way, it can get the child component inside `ngOnInit`